# Srange scope behavior of function kwargs

Tags: python, scope

Start with example,

```
def foo(inp, out=[]):
    out.append(inp)
    return out

if __name__=='__main__':
    print foo('asd') #return ['asd']
    print foo('bsd') #return ['asd', 'bsd']
```

I expect `out` is defined within the scope of function `foo` and would not pass to next call of the function. But as you can see after calling `foo('asd')`, calling `foo('bsd')` will have the memory of its previous call, returing `['asd', 'bsd']`. And I can't find `out` is saved in my python runtime. it is somehow stored invisibly.

Anyone has idead?

Comment: Mutable default arguments get a little tricky, check out this [link](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/mutable-default-arguments/)

Comment: @TheLazyScripter Thanks for pointing out!=]